# Video card fan spins eccentrically, is it normal?

Tags: graphics-card, fan

I've bought some hours ago a Zotac GTX 970 Omega AMP! core edition video card, and after visual inspection I've noticed that when manually making the fan spin, they move side to side after a complete loop.

It stroked me as odd, since if I understand correctly, that would cause vibration.

One thing to note, the entire fan (metallic circular plate + the fan itself) is not spinning eccentrically, only the metallic circular plate.

At first I thought it was an optical illusion because of the logo printed, but then after watching closely it's not the case.

If you need a video or something I can make one.

EDIT: Added video to clarify the weird spin: https://vid.me/nhar

Comment: Have you actually plugged it in?  I don't really see a question.

Comment: No, I noticed the strange behavior after manually spinning them.

Comment: Do you mean the sticker they stick on fans?

Comment: http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500363

After zooming in to the logos on the fans, there are indeed stickers on them.  Make sure you're not seeing just the stickers but the actual fan moving sideways.

It is extremely unlikely for this to be an actual manufacturing defect because it would mean means the axis is in the wrong place, and the fan shouldn't even be able to spin if that happens.

Comment: @Artemix - After you have properly installed the fans, provided them power, come back if its stil a problem.

Comment: Video added, notice that the logos are not creating an illusion of eccentricity, the metallic discs are indeed spinning like that.

(Oh, and that model you linked is not the same I have, mine is a "core edition", it has three fans.

Comment: It is just the sticker that is off-center.  However, at high speed, it could cause some vibration and uneven wear on the spindle.  Another possibility: it is purposely placed off-center to help balance the fan, similar to adding wheel weights to your tires.

Comment: Did you watch the video?.

Comment: Yes, based on the video.  Power them up and put your finger on the side of the fan housing.  If you can feel vibration, return it for replacement.  If you can't feel vibration, don't worry about it.  BTW, unless you use @username to address comments, nobody will get an alert that your comment is there if there is more than one other person associated with the post.

Comment: @fixer1234 based on the video there is no way that you noticed that only the sticker is off-center.

Comment: Watch the outline of the fan blades and the space between it and the housing.  That doesn't move but the sticker does.  However, the proof is in the pudding, as they say.  Regardless of what is or isn't off-center, if the blades + sticker aren't balanced, it will vibrate at high speed.  You should be able to feel that if you touch the fan housing.  If you can't feel any vibration, you don't have a problem.